# Substitution/change of variable in integration

Tags: calculus

Integration techniques are newbies to me right now, and I was assigned this integral. My professor recommend to use substitution/change of variable to integrate this function.

$$\int (x^6+x^3)\sqrt[3]{x^3+2} dx$$

He gave me a hint after asking him for help and told me ¨Look at what is inside the cubic root, so that when you take the derivative of what is in the inside, you get what is on the outside of the cubic root. So that this works, you could try to factorize something out of x^3+2, that way when you derivee it , the outcome can help you with everything that is on the outside of the cubic root.¨
I was thinking for example **x^3+2 = x^3(1+2x^-3)**

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite the integral as

$$\int x\color{red}{x^2}(x^3+1)\sqrt[3]{\color{red}{x^3+1}+1}\,\mathrm dx$$

then substitute $u=x^3+1$ (which gives $x=\sqrt[3]{u-1}$)  and $\mathrm du=3x^2\,\mathrm dx$ to get

$$\frac13\int\sqrt[3]{u-1}u\sqrt[3]{u+1}\,\mathrm du=\frac13\int u\sqrt[3]{u^2-1}\,\mathrm du$$

Then another substitution, $v=u^2-1$ and $\mathrm dv=2u\,\mathrm du$, leaving you with

$$\frac16\int\sqrt[3]{v}\,\mathrm dv$$